# Solving System of Linear Equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

These are the two known equations:

$$\frac{(I_2+I_3)-(I_1+I_4)}{I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4} = \frac{2x}{L}$$
$$\frac{(I_2+I_4)-(I_1+I_3)}{I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4} = \frac{2y}{L}$$

where I know the values of $(x,y,L)$.
How can I find the values of $(I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4)$?

Comment: I think you can add more condition,because this can't  find it, it is clear there are infiitity many solution